# URL Re write in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting

how to rewrite url in zend? My url is like 
http://xyz.com/richmath_n/beta/cms/showdetail/id/2
and i want url like http://xyz.com/richmath_n/beta/aboutus
where aboutus is any text No controller and action is defined for it

Comment: ZF1 or ZF2? http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html Look at Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment